# Creating projects via Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, eclipse

I installed Spring Tools Suite 3.9.1 release in eclipse oxygen. It causes problems in all my projects, whether simple java projects or spring projects.

This message comes whenever I open my eclipse.

> 'Loading spring static imports into eclipse code assist favourites' has encountered a problem. An internal error occurred during: "Loading spring static imports into eclipse code assist favourites".

Comment: Try a short of uninstalling and reinstalling program from zip should fix your problem.

Comment: Installing from a local file, the second time did the trick.